# prevent button submit form onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem on html button tag

This my html code

```
<form name="data_kirim" action="confirm_order.php" method="POST">

        ..... order input field ....

    <button class="back_button" onclick="window.location.href='keranjang.php'">Back</button>
    <input class="next_button" type="submit" name="submit_data_kirim" value="Next"/>
</form>
```

How to prevent button to submit this form, because button is using the href to back page,

Can someone help me?

Comment: Make the type as `button` instead of `submit`. Call a JS function to do what you need to.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<button class="back_button" onclick="window.location.href='keranjang.php'">Back</button>
<form name="data_kirim" action="confirm_order.php" method="POST">
<input class="next_button" type="submit" name="submit_data_kirim" value="Next"/>
</form>
```

A quick solution would be to move the back button outside the form since It's not using the form inputs anyway.

Answer (score 5):

change

```
type='submit'
```

to

```
type='button'
```

Comment: Thanks man, I got this issue and this is the simplest and easiest solution. I couldn't understand why a button make submit without being an input... Thanks Anyway!!

Comment: Submit is made that way, submit simply means to submit the form and it does the same either you input something or not. So, in order to escape this, we use button, so we could process  other things before we manually submit the form.

Answer (score 2):

you can call a function in javascript when click your button, redirect to your link and `return false` or use `preventDefault()` function with jquery

Answer (score 1):

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
```

Comment: this code will always prevent the action. no matter true action or not

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just make it link to another page and not submit the form then simply make it a normal button like so :

```
<a href="URL">Next</a>
```

This will not submit the form though.